# CakePHP 3 regex validation

Tags: cakephp

I'm trying to do a regex in a custom validation rule to allow any character except numbers but can't get working.

```
public function validationDefault(Validator $validator)
{        
        $validator
            ->requirePresence('username')
            ->notEmpty('username', 'A username is required.')
            ->alphaNumeric('username', 'A username must be alphanumeric.')  
            ->add('username', 'validChars',[
                //'rule' => ['custom', '([0-9])'], // PASSED - Excepts anything but must have a number.
                'rule' => ['custom', '([^0-9])'], // FAILED - Excepts anything but NOT a number.
                'message' => 'Excepts anything except a number.'
            ]) 
            ->requirePresence('password')
            ->notEmpty('password', 'A password is required.');

            return $validator;
}
```

Thanks for any help.
Z.

Comment: explain **Excepts anything but NOT a number.** with an example

Comment: By anything I mean any character from all the unicode blocks (https://unicode-table.com/en/blocks/) that is not numeric. IE: Use alphaNumeric() to filter all the unicode block characters to leave letters and numbers then a custom rule to take out the numbers and you have accepted input for a persons name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a custom validation rule, with an anonymous function

```
public function validationDefault(Validator $validator)
{        
    $validator
        ->requirePresence('username')
        ->notEmpty('username', 'A username is required.')
        ->alphaNumeric('username', 'A username must be alphanumeric.')  
        ->add('username', 'validChars',[ 
            'rule' => function ($value, $context) {
                return !preg_match('/[0-9]/', $value); //Return true if no number is present in the value     
            },
            'message' => 'Excepts anything except a number.'
        ]) 
        ->requirePresence('password')
        ->notEmpty('password', 'A password is required.');

        return $validator;
}
```